# Post request making an async await db call not returning correct result. Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I think I need help with understanding async await functionality.

I make a Post request that is async:

```
app.post('/updateprofile', upload.none(), async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let retData = await mainController.updateProfile(req.body, mysql, connectionParams);
        console.log(retData);
        res.status(200).send(retData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

As you can tell the post request makes a call to an async function called updateProfile that's in my main controller:

```
updateProfile: async function (formData, mysql, connectionParams) {
    console.log("l");
    con = mysql.createConnection(connectionParams);
    const result = await con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }

        return result;
    });
    con.end();
    console.log("k");
    if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
        console.log('ffff');
        return "OK"
    } else {
        console.log("22");
        return "Fail";
    }
}
```

For some reason the result.affectedRows is always < 0. So my return is always a Fail. I thought by using the await functionality the sql call would wait before going to the next compiled if statement. I tried of course using async in different forms. I understand I shouldn't need to use Promises since Promises are happening "behind the scenes" in the await/async functionality. What could I be doing wrong?

result.affectedRow is undefined when I show it in the console log outside the sql query in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a callback, then `con.query` will not return `promise`. You have either pass callback or use without callback in try-catch

**Else write logic in callback:**

```
updateProfile: async function fn(formData, mysql, connectionParams) {
  console.log("l");
  con = mysql.createConnection(connectionParams);
  return new Promise((r, rej) => {
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        rej(err);
      }
      con.end();
      if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
        r("OK");
      } else {
        rej("Fail");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

With Async-Await:

```
async function fn(formData, mysql, connectionParams) {
  console.log("l");
  con = mysql.createConnection(connectionParams);
  try {
    const result = con.query(sql);
    if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
      return "OK";
    } else {
      return "FAIL";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(err);
    return "FAIL";
  } finally {
    con.end();
  }
}
```

With the document `con.query` does not seems return promise. Returning from `callback` wont make it promisble. You can make a function promisable using node js util.
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);

async function callStat() {
  const stats = await stat('.');
  console.log(`This directory is owned by ${stats.uid}`);
}
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Comment: Hmm.. yeah I'm trying to avoid "Callback hell". I'm just trying to figure this out before I move to more complex post requests. So, Yeah I see promisify is used in this article https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628 but in a lot of other articles online, nobody mentions promisify when using await on a con.query.

Comment: For example here: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/ the person doesn't use promisify.

Comment: I have updated answer, please check. i think it will solve ur problem

Comment: I need to avoid call backs, currently for one of my post requests I have 5 nested queries which could get worse in the future.

Comment: If you pass callback, than it will be not promise anymore.. u have pass callbeck. use without callback. in try catch

Comment: I have added with async-await sample, if works for u. Accept as answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm implementing promisify to mitigate nesting of multiple queries.